# How can I simplify settings.gradle after I prevent Intellij Idea from crashing when processing multiple Gradle projects?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I store my solutions to various coding exercises in one repository as Gradle projects. One solution - one Gradle project. I have near 100 Gradle projects in one repository. The structure of the whole repository looks like this:

```
repository_name  
├── topic1  
│   ├── exercise1  
│   │   ├── build.gradle  
│   │   └── settings.gradle  
│   ├── exercise2  
│   │   ├── build.gradle  
│   │   └── settings.gradle  
│   └── exercise3  
│       ├── build.gradle  
│       └── settings.gradle  
├── topic2  
│   ├── exercise1  
│   └── exercise2  
└── topic3
```

[Perhaps a clearer view in the form of an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Typig.png)

"repository name" and "topic*" are directories that consist of directories only, only "exercises*" are gradle projects as I mentioned before.

The problem is that when I open my whole project (repository) in IntelliJ IDEA it tries to load all these projects at the same time, all system resources go to 100% and then IntelliJ IDEA just stops responding, so I can't work with my projects anymore.

I did what the JetBrains employee advised to do at this [link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-210255/Gradle-refresh-spawns-JVM-for-every-module-slow) at youtrack.jetbrains.com portal (and it helped)

I add the repository_name/settings.gradle file and this is what it contains:

```
includeBuild("topic1/exercise1")
includeBuild("topic1/exercise2")
includeBuild("topic1/exercise3")
includeBuild("topic2/exercise1")
//for linux
includeBuild("topic1\\exercise1")
includeBuild("topic1\\exercise2")
includeBuild("topic1\\exercise3")
includeBuild("topic2\\exercise1")
//for windows
```

As you can imagine I have 100 + 100 lines in these files. I tried

```
includeBuild("topic1\\*")
```

and it didn't work.

Is there a way to simplify this file and add some platform independence?
Something like this:

```
if (windows) {
  includeBuild("topic1\\*")
  includeBuild("topic2\\*")
  includeBuild("topic3\\*")
} 
if (debian) {
  includeBuild("topic1/*")
  includeBuild("topic2/*")
  includeBuild("topic3/*")
}
```

Comment: Windows should support / as directory path separator as well. I just tried it on the Windows Explorer and works with no problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot, with your help I was able to reduce the number of the lines in two times :) 
I hope I can able to reduce it even more somehow, because it's not really convenient to put a new line in this file when you create a new gradle project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved all topics directories to separate folder for simplicity and this is how settings.gradle file looks now:

```
file('exercises').eachDir { topic ->
    topic.eachDir { exercise ->
        includeBuild("exercises/${topic.name}/${exercise.name}")
    }
}
```